# jQuery to PHP to Highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I've been getting values from my jquery and pass it to my PHP.I am getting the right value, the problem is my highchart does not display the data using the value I got from my jQuery.here are my scripts.

```
<?php
    include ('connect.php');
    $years = array(2011=>'Select  year','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030');
    $year_count= count($years);
    $year = $year_count + 2010;
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#years").change(function(event)
   {
      var y=$(this).val();
      if(y!='2011' || y!='NULL')
      {
          alert(y);
          $("#memcount").load('reports/yearly_sales.php', {"y":y});
         $("#top10").load('reports/yearly_customers.php', {"y":y});
      }
   });
});
```

```
Year: <select id="years">
<?php
for($yr=2011; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
}
?>
```

here is my php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['y'])) 
 {
$y = $_POST['y'];

 ?>

<div id='top10' style='width: 680px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

    <?php
     $months = array();
     $jan_tot = 0;
     $feb_tot = 0;
    //jan
    $jan = mysql_query("SELECT count(customer_id) AS count_id, date_added FROM `customer` WHERE date_added LIKE '$y-01-%'");
    while($janfetch = mysql_fetch_array($jan))
    {
        $jan_tot=(int)$janfetch['count_id'];
    }

    //feb
    $feb = mysql_query("SELECT count(customer_id) AS count_id FROM `customer` WHERE date_added LIKE '$y-02-%'");
    while($febfetch = mysql_fetch_array($feb))
    {
        $feb_tot=(int)$febfetch['count_id'];
    }
     }
    ?>
```

thanks for those who will be helping me.I need this a lot.

Comment: I already saw my error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\artistikav2\reports\yearly_sales.php on line 28" but I don't know how to fix this. help please.

Comment: check your query with mysql_num_rows and if it didn't return 0 then use mysql_fetch_array

Comment: i'm already using mysql_fetch_array.I used this "$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id='5' AND date_added LIKE '$year-01-%'";$jan = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());" to check what my error and it returned the whole query that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order`  WHERE  `order_status_id`='5' AND
                                        `date_added` LIKE '".$year."-01-%'";

$jan = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```